# Que puede ser mi APP funciona correctamente en Android 5 y no funciona correctamente ne Android 7 transfiriendo datos a un Webservice?

Tags: android

Mi APP transfiriere por hiloconexion atravez de una URL la informaciona a un Webservice, lo pruebo en un celular con Android 5 y transfiere los datos correctamente, cuando la corro en un celular con Andorid 7 no transfiere.

Mi APP esta desarrollada en Android Studio, en el celular que no funciona es:

Samsung
Galaxy A5
con Android 7.0

Comment: Descarga el api de android 7 y en el build.gradle verifica la versión del api que maneja.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código de cómo realizas la conexión al web-service? Así es muy difícil saber que está sucediendo. ¿Usaste alguna característica que requiere algún Permiso en Ejecución (típico de las versiones >= 6) y te cierra la app con un java.lang.SecurityException? Brindamos más información.